# Separate one String with ',' character into two new String

Tags: java, mysql

A MySQL table called item_list has a field named description, the problem is the previous programmer combined the name and description of the item in one field called description. The data is now at 20k+. Now I am going to have a problem during migration.So how do I separate one

```
String description="BEARING, ROLLER 23230CKE4 SPHERICAL"
```

into two new strings

```
String name="BEARING" 
String description="ROLLER 23230CKE4 SPHERICAL"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use String.split(); http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Doing this in either Java or SQL would be reasonably simple, but you need to pick one, and you need to show us an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: the database is in mysql, and i am using java to separate the string. Okay i will try..thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way

```
String description="BEARING, ROLLER 23230CKE4 SPHERICAL";
String [] arr=description.split(",");
System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

**output**

```
BEARING
ROLLER 23230CKE4 SPHERICAL
```

String Split methods returns an array of strings.As in the String description has one comma(,) So the whole string will be splited into 2 strings.

Comment: `split(",\\s*")`, or similar, would be better (and your output isn't a direct copy and paste of the actual output, it's missing a leading space).

Comment: yes, using description.split(",\\s*") instead of description.split(",") removes the space..thank you Dukeling

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer

something like this

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(description,",");
 String name=st.nextToken();
 description=st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately string split functions will not work correctly if there is more than 1 `,` in the combined string.

I recommend you split on the first `,` only.

```
int idx = description.indexOf(',');
if (idx != -1) { // if there is a comma
    name = description.substring(0, idx);
    description = description.substring(idx+1);
} else {
    ???? // no comma in description
}
```

Answer (score 0):

combination of all the answers.., that solve the problem.

```
String  name="",new_d ="";
String description="BEARING, ROLLER 23230CKE4 SPHERICAL";

int idx = description.indexOf(',');
if (idx != -1) { // if there is comma
String arr[]=description.split(",\\s*");
name=arr[0].toString();
new_d=arr[1].toString();
} 
else {
            // if there is no comma
name=description;
new_d="";
}
System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(new_d);
```